# How to install & import Java "HttpClient" Library

Tags: java, httpclient

So I'm a C++ Programmer who is trying to learn Java in order to write a client-side https receptor application, corresponding to a particular website.

**My Problem:**
I found this wonderful-looking Java library online, called "HttpClient" (See https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html).
Unfortunately, the only way to install the library is manually (download a .zip file with all the .jar files in it). I understand that the include paths are meant to look something like this

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpMethodParams;
```

But I have no idea how to configure the "CLASSPATH" Environment Variable in order to reflect this (please note that I know HOW to set the variable, just not WHAT to set it to).

**My Question:**
Could someone please explain to me (in laymen's terms) how to download & setup this library onto my Windows 10 PC such that I can implement the above `include` statements in my code?

Comment: I apologize in advance for being such a tremendous noob when it comes to Java

Comment: Are you using an IDE like Eclipse?

Comment: You need to have it on classpath both when compiling and when running the resulting app. The classpath needs to include the paths to all the needed jars. Compiling and running it using an IDE or a build tool like Maven helps a lot to avoid writing the classpath manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install a build/dependency management tool such as [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) (there are others).  Then you will simply need to add the following to your project pom.xml and maven will handle the rest.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

If you'd like to manually handle adding the .jar (and it's dependencies) you can specify "CLASSPATH=path/to/your.jar" or when running use "java -cp path/to/your.jar

Comment: I tried this, but Maven gave me an error saying it couldn't find the library. Is there somewhere I need to enter the path to my HttpComponents library?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that each of the `.jar` files it comes with are in your `CLASSPATH`.

e.g.

```
export MY_INSTALL_DIR=/some_dir/httpcomponents-client-4.5.2/lib
export CLASSPATH=$MY_INSTALL_DIR/commons-codec-1.9.jar:$MY_INSTALL_DIR/commons-logging-1.2.jar
```

and so on... I did the first two `CLASSPATH` elements above, and you ultimately need one element for each of 10 or so JARs I see in the dist.

Think of the `.jar` files as something like `.so` or `.dll` files - the compiled binaries.  Think of this as the equivalent of putting `.so` or `.dll` files in your `PATH`.

In my example, I set the `CLASSPATH` via environment properties, like a `.bashrc` file or the like. Since you're on Windows, you would use the Windows environment variables available via the Advanced System Settings control panel.  You can also set them via the command line (`javac -classpath` and `java -classpath`), via your build tools, or other ways. I found a couple of helpful links that discuss this:  [this one](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/10/5-ways-to-add-multiple-jar-to-classpath-java.html) and [this other one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html).

Long-term, you should learn how to use [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), like the other answers here suggest, but first get to grips w/ Java basics.  Just so you know, Maven is something like `nmake` from your world, plus the ability to automatically download and manage 3rd party dependencies, plus a whole lot of other features.

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is  put the jar in your project's classpath..This can be done in multiple ways depending upon whether you are using any build tools like maven,gradle etc.
But since you are new to java,I suggest you  download the jar from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar.zip) and extract it and put it into *any folder which is added to your classpath*.

If you have created a webproject then by default `WebContent->WEB-INF->lib` is already in your calsspath. So just paste the .jar file into this file and you will be good to go.

If you are using maven or gradle or ivy then refer here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2

**N.B.:you don't need to add anything to your windows classpath or modify any path variables of your OS. these are all project specific classpaths. So do it your project. Use a build tool like maven if you wish to access these more easily. Also recommended is to use eclipse or netbeans or some other mordern IDE**

Answer (score 0):

If your project is `maven` then you can add dependencies in `pom.xml` as say above

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
      </dependency>
```

If your project is not a `maven` type then simply download the `jar` and add this `jar` file to the `lib` Folder. Your dependency will automatically resolved. No bug will raised due to dependency.